# jQuery - Generate prices from selection, dynamically sum column, post total amount form

Tags: jquery, sum, html-select, dynamically-generated

what I would like to create is a table with:

1. selection of country [when selected it generates the description in shipment-field and the respective price in the price-field]
2. fixed product name and fixed price [easy :-)]
3. selection of accessory [it generates the respective price in price-field]
4. total amount generated summing the 3 prices
5. submit total amount with form method="post"

[Image example](http://www.ideata.it/download/Shipment.png)
This is the idea of code that needs jQuery implementation:

```
<form action="product.php" method="post">
<h2>Select Country shipment</h2>
<select>
<option>USA $1.00</option>
<option>CANADA $2.00</option>
<option>EUROPE $3.00</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td width="200"></td>
<td width="60"><strong>Price</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product</td>
<td>10.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span id="shipment_text"></span></td>
<td><span id="shipment_price"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Accessory1">Accessory 1 - $1.00</option>
    <option value="Accessory2">Accessory 2 - $2.00</option>
    <option value="Accessory3">Accessory 3 - $3.00</option>
</select></td>
<td><span id="accessory_price"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
<td><span id="total"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="hidden" id="total" name="amount" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you also put the country selection dropdown inside the table?

Comment: Where's the jQuery you've written and are currently having trouble with?

Comment: Agree with gn22, have you tried anything yet? Otherwise I can post an answer with links to the jquery methods you will likely use. I doubt anyone will want to solve this entire thing for you...

Answer (score 1):

To do something when the country select is changed, use this:

```
$("#country").change(function() {
    /*update description and shipping price/*
});
```

Note you need to add `id="country"` to the country select. You can then do a similar thing with the other selects.

Alternatively, you can attach the same event to all the selects, and in the event handler get all the selected options so that everything happens in the same place:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var country = $("#country option:selected").val();
    var accessory = $("#accessories option:selected").val();
    /* Update all selects, prices, and total accordingly */
});
```

Note that you should put `value` attributes on all the options as identifiers. These will likely be the prices as raw numbers. Use [window.parseFloat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) to convert from an attribute string to a number.

The important concepts here are [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/).

As for submitting the form, your submit button should do the trick. If you want to manually control the request and parameters, you can use [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), and there is an example of this on that documentation page.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/aRDXD/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/tyAmg/

Lemme know if this dont help will remove my post.

Also note `:)` your amount is in `$` but total is in `euro` :P

**code**

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('.sum').each(function(){

       sum += parseInt($(this).attr("value").replace('$',''));
    });

    $('#total').html(sum);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="product.php" method="post">
<h2>Select Country shipment</h2>
<select class="sum">
<option value="$1.00">USA $1.00</option>
<option value="$2.00">CANADA $2.00</option>
<option value="$3.00">EUROPE $3.00</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td width="200"></td>
<td width="60"><strong>Price</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product</td>
<td class="sum" value="10.00">10.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span id="shipment_text"></span></td>
<td><span id="shipment_price"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="sum">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1.00">Accessory 1 - $1.00</option>
    <option value="2.00">Accessory 2 - $2.00</option>
    <option value="3.00">Accessory 3 - $3.00</option>
</select></td>
<td><span id="accessory_price"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
<td><span id="total"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="hidden" id="total" name="amount" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Looks good although you're getting NaN when no accessory is selected. Also it's silly to store the prices in the value attribute with a '$' in there and then replace it with "" every time. Just make it a number.

Comment: @TonyR Thanks bruv, sure will, `:)` Howz you?